# How to connect to Realm Object Server from .NET code (Xamarin)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I have a running Realm Object Server on my Mac (192.168.100.61:9080 ip), and Xamarin App on PC. 
I want to save/synchronize data on the ROS.
How I can to connect to ROS from code?

Comment: This might help get better responses on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login/register a user and open a synchronized Realm. Something like:

```
// pass createUser: true to register rather than login
var credentials = Credentials.UsernamePassword("foo@bar.com", "super-secure", createUser: false);

// Login the user
var user = await User.LoginAsync(credentials, new Uri("http://192.168.100.61:9080"));

// Create a sync configuration for the Realm
// Notice the URL uses the realm scheme and not http
var config = new SyncConfiguration(user, new Uri("realm://192.168.100.61:9080/~/myrealm"));

// Finally, get the Realm instance
// This Realm will be kept in sync with the remote one
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
```

For more details, check out the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#logging-in-the-user).